# Print adjacent cell with random.choice in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file which catalogues dumb things my friends say in Discord for a ".quote" command. The Discord side of this I think I have handled and can implement myself, but I have a question about actually working with the csv file.

```
import csv
import random

col=3
with open("filedirectoryhere", "r") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    data=[row[col] for row in reader]
print(random.choice(data))
```

So right now, the above code block is correctly returning a random quote from column D:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMxqB.png
(I can't embed my image because I don't have enough rep on stackoverflow)

But I'd also like to return the adjacent cell (C) and get the quote author as well, after getting the random choice. I have read some CSV tutorials but none of them really cover this unless I'm just completely blanking. I know that as a workaround, I could just merge the data and have it pull a random quote with the author's name as part of the Cell in column D, but I'd like to know if there is a way to keep this data separate and still make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could store cell C and D as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) instead of just cell D.

Like this:

```
import csv
import random

col=3

with open("filedirectoryhere", "r") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    data=[(row[col-1], row[col]) for row in reader]
print(random.choice(data))
```

This should print the author and the quote respectively.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I upvoted but my votes aren't publicly displayed because I'm new.